# Defer Parsing Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

im wondering how can i fix this?

i've already defer the other .js files, and this are the remaining js files ..

[image: Defer Parsing of Javascript]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Also you can use async property of <script> tag to enable non-render blocking loading of js script (see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp)

Comment: thanks @metamaker i'll try it :D

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

[Recaptcha documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) provides you with the correct example, which in this case I've added above. You should add that script tag before your closing `</body>` tag.

Or, you could enqueue it in the footer by using the $in_footer parameter of [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script('stack-recaptcha','https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js','','',true); // $handle, $src, $dep, $ver, $in_footer
```

The first method is the preferred method, to take advantage of the `async defer` attributes of the script tag.